# How to color rows from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a simple SELECT statement am running within powershell code and then export the rows into csv format.

```
$query1 = "select * from table1"

$DatasourceFullList = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ResultsInstance -Database $ResultsDatabase -Query $Query1 
    $NameOfFile = " DS list_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
    $FileToOutput = "\\server\c$\Output\$NameOfFile"
    $DatasourceFullList | Export-csv $FileToOutput -NoTypeInformation 
    $attachment1 = $FileToOutput
```

Some rows are flagged with 'YES' and some 'NO', How can I add a colour to those that are flagged with 'YES' only. Is Possible?

Note that am using MS SQL Server.

Thank you!

Comment: CSV files don't contain any formatting markup, they're just flat data. Excel can apply conditional formatting, but those rules aren't persisted in files unless they're in Excel's native format. You can create Excel files directly in PowerShell, either by automating Excel or using one of the .NET libraries for that, but that's quite a bit of extra work just to add a dash of color.

Comment: Use SSRS to create a report, color it as you want and then save as Excel, csv or in any other format

Comment: As @JeroenMostert stated, you could use the Excel Com Object to create a xlsx file with the color formatting you want, other recommended options are HTML or RichText but that depends on whether you want to reuse the data or just display it as text.